# PHP and Doxygen with multiple property declaration

Tags: php, properties, doxygen, multiline, variable-declaration

I finally got doxygen to work with php and PHPDoc styled comments (I'm removing '@package' with filter since it breaks up doxygen) though there's one thing I would love to have and are not able to figure out how.

In PHP I'm writing multiple property declaration in a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
private
    /// the blue color
    $blue,
    /// the red color
    $red,
    /// the yellow color
    $yellow;

public
    /// the orange color
    $orange,
    /// black (no color)
    $black;

public function bar() {}
}
```

If I'm now generating the docs, only the first property is shown as `private Attribute` while all other properties are simply referenced as `Data Fields`. So doxygen obviously doesn't parse the accesors of every property after the first one.

**Is it possible to make this commentation style compatible to doxygen ?**

P.S: I thought about applying a filter which converts it in doxygen-parsable code style. Though this would only be a fix I'm currently working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this filter, that works for the example you provided. I think it should also work for more complex examples.

```
// Get the input
$source = file_get_contents($argv[1]);

$count = 0;

do {
    $source = preg_replace('#(private|public|protected)(\s*[^$]*)(\$[^,;]+),#',
                           "$2 $1 $3;\n$1 ", $source, -1, $count);
} while($count > 0);

// Output
echo $source;
```

You can find this and other filters at my GitHub repository [doxygen-php-filters](https://github.com/AbcAeffchen/doxygen-php-filters).